# Optional Script in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that utilizes a couple of environment variables, and I want to use them in my script.

The script I have looks like this, and I want `$BUILD_SCRIPT` to only be run if it's provided, otherwise to ignore it. (It's just a simple string with a command, such as `npm run && npm build`)

```
git push $GITHUB_REPOSITORY $BRANCH:$BRANCH && \

# Builds the project if applicable.
if [ -z "$BUILD_SCRIPT" ]
then
  $BUILD_SCRIPT && \\
fi

# Commits the data to Github.
git add -f $FOLDER &&
```

The problem I'm having is that I get this error: `Syntax error: "fi" unexpected` - But if I remove the `fi` I get another error stating that the end of file was expected.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: whats the trailing `&&` for??

Comment: It's there because I want it to run whatever is in `$BUILD_SCRIPT` and then move onto the next line afterwards. I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to bash though so maybe it's not needed?

Comment: correct, drop them and the script should run fine (assuming the env variables are set up correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to just be some unnecessary trailing characters...

```
git push $GITHUB_REPOSITORY $BRANCH:$BRANCH

# Builds the project if applicable.
if [ -z "$BUILD_SCRIPT" ]
then
  $BUILD_SCRIPT
fi

# Commits the data to Github.
git add -f $FOLDER
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work even if `$BUILD_SCRIPT` is defined. It doesn't seem to execute the commands provided in the variable. If `$BASH_SCRIPT` is defined I want it to execute the commands inbetween, for instance `git push && npm install && git add`.

Comment: what is the value of $BUILD_SCRIPT ?